# updateCell in Zend Gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have loaded the Zend Gdata library and using an example successfully read rows in my Google spreadsheet but the updateCell example keeps on failing.

On checking updateCell doesnt appear to be in the library.

Has anyone had this problem? I am using Zend Gdata-1.12.0

```
$row=1;
$col=1;
$inputValue=99;
$worksheetId="od6";
$googleDocs->updateCell ( 1, 1, 'test', $Key, $worksheetId);
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
$feed = $spreadSheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
$updatedCell = updateCell($row,$col,$inputValue,$Key,$worksheetId);
```

Comment: Looks like the function is there in the API docs -http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/db_Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets.html . May be you are calling it with the wrong object?

Answer (score 1):

The updateCell method is part of the $spreadSheetService, you need to add $spreadSheetService-> in front of the call to updateCell.

```
$updatedCell = $spreadSheetService->updateCell($row,$col,$inputValue,$Key,$worksheetId);
```